# Excel data mapping

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have two different data sheets in excel like below.

1st: A is first  column B is second

A -> B

2nd: B is first  column C is second

B -> C

I want to add them together so I can get

A -> B -> C  values mapped correctly.

The problem is there is about 50K value in each column, some of them are empty and values are not in order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` formula on the C column of the first sheet

See this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) or [this one](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/) to understand how to use the `VLOOKUP` statement.

If you want more precise help, show us some data so that we will help you building the formula.